# validar formulario antes de enviar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo un formulario en `HTML` el cual quiero validar antes de su envío. He intentado utilizar la función `validate()` pero esto no me funciona. Podría alguien indicarme como podría hacerlo o en qué estoy fallando?. Adjunto código Javascript.

```
$('#confirmarPartido').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'confirmar_partido.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#crearPartido').serialize(),

        beforeSend: function validarDatos(){
            $('#crearPartido').validate({
                rules:{
                    deporte: "required",
                    ciudad_evento: "required",
                    espacio_deportivo: "required",
                    direccion: "required",
                    fecha: "required",
                    hora: "required",
                    stars: "required",
                    equipo: "required",
                }
            })
        },

        success: function partidoCreado(confirmacion){
            if(confirmacion=='confirmado'){
                $('#modalConfirmado').modal();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.href= 'perfil.html';
                },1000);
            }
            else{
                alert('Error creando el partido');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar el formulario usando en la etiqueta form el siguiente elemento

```js
<form method="" action="" onsubmit="return validarFormulario()">
```

Y en la función de JavaScript devuelves `false` o `true`, te pongo un ejemplo en el que quiero validar si el nombre tiene más de 3 carácteres, en caso de ser mayor a 3 el formulario se enviaría.

```js
function validarFormulario() {
  nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

  if (nombre.length > 3) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```